# Use of alias in /etc/hosts or ssh_config

Tags: ssh, hosts

I'm have configured a bastion or (jump) box to access a virtual private network.

```
#ssh_config
Host bastion
HostName 14.90.140.120
User me
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me
ForwardAgent yes

Host 10.1.*
User me
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me
ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W %h:%p
```

I am able to ssh into both the bastion and 10.1.1.6 address with no issues.

What I would like to be to do is add an entry like the following. Note: I have not time for DNS at the moment, but it would be my preferred approach.

```
#/etc/hosts
10.1.1.6    my-host-inside-vpc.corp.internal
```

When I do that however and try to access the machine I get the following

```
➜  ~ ssh -vvv my-host-inside-vpc.corp.internal
     debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
     debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
     debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
     debug1: Connecting to my-host-inside-vpc.corp.internal [10.1.1.6] port 22.
```

At this point the operation times out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Host` matches the name you use when you connect, **not** the ip after dns resolution.

Try using `Host *corp.internal` instead.

Per our discussion in the comments if you want to use the symbolic names, yet are required to resolve them to IPs for the bastion host, then you could use a sub-expressionist in the ProxyCommand like this.

```
ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W $(getent hosts $h | cut -d " " -f1):%p
```

Comment: Triad that and I now receive -
Executing proxy command: exec ssh bastion -W my-host-inside-vpc.corp.internal:22
......
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: Is it possible to resolve and expand the ip in the ProxyCommand?

Comment: Stuff in the proxycommand is a command.  You could possibly put in something like `ProxyCommand ssh bastion -W $(getent hosts %h):%p`.  I haven't tested that though.  Basically just figure out a shell expression that will resolve the name and return the IP from the subexpression.

Comment: I added the following to extract the ip  getent hosts $h | cut -d " " -f1. If you add as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Ok, I have updated.