# ssh tunneling with hostname in /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, ssh, mac-osx, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to ssh to destination host via a jump box. Below is my config file entry

```
Host 172.* 
   User surendra
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ProxyCommand ssh -q -A surendra@jump nc -q0 %h %p
```

This works fine when I SSH to destination box with IP address.  But when i am trying to SSH with hostname this will not work.

Note: I made an entry in my /etc/hosts file as well.

Can someone please help how to configure the .ssh/config file so that i can ssh  to destination box using the hostname by looking the hostname entry in my /etc/hosts file.

Comment: What does the name resolve to when you try? Does it show the correct ip?

Comment: since the hostname entry is in my localbox i.e.(/etc/hosts) it didn't resolve to anything. Note: We don't have a internal DNS to resolve the hostname.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/801395/use-of-alias-in-etc-hosts-or-ssh-config/801407#801407

Comment: Hi, In my case the /etc/hosts file is like this.    10.10.10.1    abc 10.10.10.2   xyz      10.10.10.3    pqr  so what should be the Host naming section should be.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-W`:

```
Match exec grep %h /etc/hosts
    [...]
    ProxyCommand ssh -W  %h:%p -q -A surendra@jump
```

It will resolve the hostnames from your local machine and not from the jumpbox.

It will also check if your host is mentioned in the `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: It's not working.  I have the hostname entry in /etc/hosts file but when i use nslookup command it's not resolving. So even if i use -W option how come it will get resolve.

Comment: You certainly need to adjust the `Host` block to match your hostname you are using. It is using what you write on the commandline, not what was resolved.

Comment: So what should be Host block name if i want to use the hostname as well as IP.

Comment: `Host 172.* your_magic_hostname`

Comment: I have some 100+ hosts, I can't add all of them any alternate way to do this.

Comment: So you can create `exec` rule in `Match`, for example `Match exec grep %h /etc/hosts`

Comment: so do i need to place this line Match exec grep %h /etc/hosts in my .ssh/config file

Answer (score 1):

Another way to workaround this is to make hostname/ip mapping entries on both  your local machine  and on the jumpbox /etc/hosts file.

Ex. Let us assume that the machine you are trying to proxy into is 10.xx.yy.zz and you want to provide an user friendly name appserver.mycompany.com and Your Jumpbox is jumpbox.mycompany.com.

1) On your localhost /etc/hosts, make a following entry

```
10.xx.yy.zz appserver.mycompany.com
```

2) On your jumpbox's /etc/hosts, make a following entry

```
10.xx.yy.zz appserver.mycompany.com
```

Now that both your local machine and your jumpbox will be able to resolve the user friendly name to the actual IP and your ssh proxy should work with following configuration

```
Host appserver.mycompany.com
   User surendra
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ProxyCommand ssh -A surendra@jumpbox.mycompany.com -W %h:%p
```